# Django: can't include the ManyToManyField field because manually specifies a 'through' model

Tags: python, django

I googled many times and found only one solution to add custom intermediate model for two model having relation through 3rd model. And I applied as usual as suggested but still getting this issue:

> *can't include the ManyToManyField field 'terms' because 'terms' manually specifies a 'through' model*

### models.py

```
class Term(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = "tbl_term"

    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)

class Post(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = "tbl_post"

    title = models.CharField(max_length=96)
    content = models.TextField()

    terms = models.ManyToManyField("Term", through="TermRelation")

class TermRelation(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = "tbl_term_relation"

    term = models.ForeignKey("Term", db_column="id_term")
    post = models.ForeignKey("Post", db_column="id_post")
```

### admin.py

```
@admin.register(Term)
class AdminTerm(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        (None, {'fields': ['name']})
    ]

@admin.register(Post)
class AdminPost(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        (None, {'fields':['title', 'content', 'terms']})
    ]
```

Answer (score 31):

You have to change the admin to include [`InlineModelAdmin` objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects)

So, change

```
class AdminPost(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        (None, {'fields':['title', 'content', 'terms']})
    ]
```

to

```
class TermInlineAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Post.terms.through


class AdminPost(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        (None, {'fields':['title', 'content']})
    ]

    inlines = (TermInlineAdmin,)
```

Comment: Do not solve problem. Got new error: "<class 'post.models.Term'> has no ForeignKey to <class 'post.models.Post'>"

Comment: Thanks @karthikr, This works also if do:


    class TermInlineAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
        model = TermRelation


But my problem is, why Django not show a single <select> element as list to select multiple item by holding control key.

Comment: So, 4 years later, 2017/dj2.0 we still cannot use basic models in Django? Should I explain to the end user, that this only one field must be on separate tab and cannot be edited as any other field?