# Can I use unique_together on ManyToMany field?

Tags: django

I have a model `OrderPage` which is manytomany to `Site`. In Django admin, I want to restrict the selection of sites(`Site`s which belong to existing `OrderPage` can not be selected again). Can I do it with `unique_together` ? I get an error with following model `ManyToManyFields are not supported in unique_together`

```
class OrderPage(models.Model):

    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    sites = models.ManyToManyField(Site)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('id', 'sites'),)


class Order(models.Model):
    order_page = models.ForeignKey(OrderPage)


class OrderPageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    filter_horizontal = ('sites',)

admin.site.register(OrderPage, OrderPageAdmin)
```

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're trying to do.  Can a site only have one order, or can it have many?  Can an order have one site or many?

Comment: I didn't explain it clearly..just updated the question, A site can only have one orderpage, an orderpage can have many site

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If an `Site` can have only one `OrderPage`, you don't need to worry about unique_together.

Ideally you should subclass `Site` and use a `ForeignKey` from that to `OrderPage`.  That would natively give you what you're looking for: each site would be able to have one OrderPage, and each OrderPage multiple Sites.  This would be the cleanest but you would have to use your subclass throughout the program in place of the original `Site` which might be more work than you want right now.

```
class BetterSite(Site):
    order_page = models.ForeignKey('OrderPage')
```

The dirtier way is to keep your M2M and just set the `site` as unique, since there should only ever be one entry on each site in the M2M table.  You would use a 'through' table so you could set the custom uniqueness value:

```
class OrderPage(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    sites = models.ManyToManyField(Site, through='OrderPageToSite')

class OrderPageToSite(models.Model):
    order_page = models.ForeignKey(OrderPage)
    site = models.ForeignKey(Site, unique=True)
```

(Note that I've left these simple but in your FK fields you should also consider setting `on_delete` and `related_name`)

Comment: It seems there'll be no way to use `filter_horizontal = ('sites',)` if using a through table as I have to move `sites` to inline model  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20201612/django-cant-include-the-manytomanyfield-field-because-manually-specifies-a-th