# Query for Intermediate table in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a "many to many" relationship between two tables (Sample, Test) using the classes:

```
class Sample (models.Model):
    tests = ChainedManyToManyField (
                                    'Test',
                                    horizontal = True,
                                    chained_field = 'matrix',
                                    chained_model_field = 'matrix',
                                    through = 'SampleTests'
)

class Test (models.Model):
     test = models.CharField (max_length = 255, blank = True, null = True)


class SampleTests (models.Model):
          test = models.ForeignKey ('Test', models.DO_NOTHING)
          sample = models.ForeignKey ('Sample', models.DO_NOTHING)
          class Meta:
                verbose_name = "Result"
                verbose_name_plural = "Results"
```

In the Class SampleTests, I put the "verbose_name_plural =" Results "" because I plan to put one more field to put the result of each test in it.

As I want to work everything in the Django admin, I configured the admin.py adding: admin.site.register (SampleTest), so in this way I can enter from the menu to this area of ​​"Results" (SampleTest class). But when I click, it throws me this error:
**"django.core.management.base.SystemCheckError: SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:
ERRORS:
<class 'applications.lab.admin.SampleAdmin'>: (admin.E013) The value of 'fields' cannot include the ManyToManyField 'tests', because that field manually specifies a relationship model. "**

I have modified several things to be able to enter my intermediate table (lab_sample_tests) that was made automatically by Django, the class SampleTests I added later, but I can not always throw different types of errors. Obviously this must be done in another way, which surprises me because in all the examples in the documentation it is this way.
Finally, just in case I mention that to relate selection fields I added a "smart_selects" extension, that's why you can see in the Sample class: tests = ChainedManyToManyField

I hope the query and what I intend has been understood, thank you very much for your time.
Greetings

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django: can't include the ManyToManyField field because manually specifies a 'through' model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20201612/django-cant-include-the-manytomanyfield-field-because-manually-specifies-a-th)

Comment: Why do you have through table if there are no added fields, you can look further here too. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-intermediary-models and https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/12203